# Derive column vaue from different rows of another column in spark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I've spark structured stream like - 
Note that there are other columns also but I've reduced to 2 columns.

```
+---+---+
| A | B | 
+---+---+
| a | 1 | 
| b | 0 |
| c | 0 |
+---+---+
```

I want to create new column whose value will be 1 if X OR Y is TRUE ELSE 0 where possible values of X and Y are a, b or c. For instance, if I select a and c then dataframe whill be like -

```
+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+
| a | 1 | 1 |
| b | 0 | 1 |
| c | 0 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
```

Because (a = 1 OR c = 0) = 1
Similarly, if I would've select b and c then there will be 0 in C column.
What I've tried is groupBy some column like Timestamp and collect_list on B and then check if 1 is present in collected list. If yes, there will be 1 in C.

After this, I tried to inner join it with original stream back based on the basis of timestamp. But its saying - Inner join between two streaming DataFrames/Datasets is not supported.

Is there any way I can solve this problem ?

Comment: whats your X and Y?

Comment: X and Y will have values from A column i.e. a, b or c. I'll select any two out of them and OR their values of B column.

Comment: You want 1 to all rows in column C if Column B has 1 in at least row otherwise 0 in all the rows. Right?

Comment: @ManojKumarDhakd Yes